# Convert MySQL PHP - XML into JS Array

Tags: arrays, google-maps, xmlhttprequest

I´m extracting data from a php file (which connects to my database) using PHP's echo to output XML. Now I want to populate an array with the data, and can´t find a way. I have searched and found examples with JSON, AJAX, XMLHttpRequest, but nothing works.

Basically I need to convert this:

//XML parsed from .php file

```
<markers>
 <marker name="Bikes" desc="116 18" lat="4.698479" lon="-74.048111" tipo="Store"/>
 <marker name="Kooning" desc="116 16" lat="4.697316" lon="-74.044807" tipo="Store"/>
 <marker name="Bike House" desc="15 104" lat="4.692983" lon="-74.044952" tipo="Store"/>
</markers
```

into this:

// JS

```
var Store = [
             ['Bikes', 4.698479, -74.048111, '116 18'],
             ['Kooning', 4.697316, -74.044807, '116 16'],
             ['Bike House', 4.692983, -74.044952, '15 104'],
            ];
```

Thank you very much. I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: this one is probably best solved in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Answer (score 1):

If you need a javascript only way of converting the XML into a JS Array you may want to look into JXON. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JXON) is a really good article with a few algorithms to do what you'd like.

My answer requires that you have [simpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) available to your php installation. Also note that due to the xml structure, my answer puts the desc attribute second in the JS array and also includes the tipo attribute in the array. If you need an array in the exact order and values that you described then you'll need to access the attributes in your arbitrary order.

```
<?php

$xml = <<<xml
<markers>
 <marker name="Bikes" desc="116 18" lat="4.698479" lon="-74.048111" tipo="Store"/>
 <marker name="Kooning" desc="116 16" lat="4.697316" lon="-74.044807" tipo="Store"/>
 <marker name="Bike House" desc="15 104" lat="4.692983" lon="-74.044952" tipo="Store"/>
</markers>
xml;

$markers = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($markers->marker as $marker) {
    $mark_arr = array();
    foreach ($marker->attributes() as $attr) {
            $mark_arr[] = (string) $attr;
    }
    $marks_arr[] = $mark_arr;
}

echo '<script>var Store = '.json_encode($marks_arr).';</script>';

?>
```

A potentially more useful answer would be to export this to a JS object so you can access the values via the keys. Here is that answer:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<xml
<markers>
 <marker name="Bikes" desc="116 18" lat="4.698479" lon="-74.048111" tipo="Store"/>
 <marker name="Kooning" desc="116 16" lat="4.697316" lon="-74.044807" tipo="Store"/>
 <marker name="Bike House" desc="15 104" lat="4.692983" lon="-74.044952" tipo="Store"/>
</markers>
xml;

$markers = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($markers->marker as $marker) {
    $mark_arr = array();
    foreach ($marker->attributes() as $key => $attr) {
            $mark_arr[$key] = (string) $attr;
    }
    $marks_arr[] = $mark_arr;
}

echo '<script>var Store = '.json_encode($marks_arr).';</script>';
```

Comment: Daniel Thank you very much. The problem is that it has to be done inside the JS file, the PHP file exports an xml via echo, and the JS file has to get that info to populate the arrays. I don´t know if I´m in the right track with this one.

Comment: I see. I'll add another answer to handle this from the javascript side.

Comment: I've added a note to the top of my answer rather than adding another.

Comment: Thank you very much, I´ll get into that.